# htaccess rule to remove repeating string from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've a URL like this:

```
domain/mobile/mobile/ascent-c-662.html
```

I need to redirect to:

```
domain/mobile/ascent-c-662.html
```

I've tried following rule but it didn't worked:

```
RewriteRule mobile\w*(.*?)(mobile(\w*))?(\..*) mobile$1umair$3$4 [QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/mobile/mobile $1/mobile [R=301,L]
```

or Change example.com with your domain, and try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/mobile/mobile(.*) http://www.example.com/mobile$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: no it didn't worked, i'm testing it on localhost can it be the problem? it redirected me to: http://localhost/mobile/mobile/test.html, it removed root folder

Comment: I have just updated it a few seconds ago (probably while you were trying), please try again.

Comment: still same result

Comment: check this link and click CLICK ME button: https://completemedical.com/urlrewrite/

Comment: Change example.com with your domain, and try this one:

RewriteRule (.*)/mobile/mobile(.*) http://www.example.com/mobile$2 [L,R=301]

Comment: do i have to write anything else with it like RewriteEngine On or something? I'm just adding rule in httaccess file and don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Yes you should write RewriteEngine On